# RTL8192EU new driver version

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, hardware

I'm trying to compile a wifi dongle (TL-WN821N) driver, but the make command is returning some errors

```
root@MrPoopyButtHole:/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver# make
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/build M=/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic'
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
  CC [M]  /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:41:0,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:267:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’
  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
        ^~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:268:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  init_timer(ptimer);
  ^~~~~~~~~~
  _init_timer
In file included from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:343:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  allow_signal(SIGTERM);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  do_signal
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:353:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’; did you mean ‘timer_pending’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (signal_pending (current))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      timer_pending
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:355:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’; did you mean ‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   flush_signals(current);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   do_signal
In file included from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:95:0,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/hal_com.h: At top level:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/hal_com.h:413:13: error: ‘file_path’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 extern char file_path[PATH_LENGTH_MAX];
             ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/compat.h:18:0,
                 from ./include/linux/ethtool.h:17,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:41,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:35,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/fs.h:2867:14: note: previous declaration of ‘file_path’ was here
 extern char *file_path(struct file *, char *, int);
              ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/drv_types.h:65:0,
                 from /home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c: In function ‘btinfo_evt_dump’:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
    if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3293:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
  DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "cid:0x%02x, len:%u\n", info->cid, info->len);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
    if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3296:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
   DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "byte2:%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s\n"
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
    if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3308:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
   DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "retry_cnt:%u\n", info->retry_cnt);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
    if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3311:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
   DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "rssi:%u\n", info->rssi);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:187:19: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  #define _seqdump seq_printf
                   ^
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/rtw_debug.h:242:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘_seqdump’
    if(_seqdump(sel, fmt, ##arg)) /*rtw_warn_on(1)*/; \
       ^~~~~~~~
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.c:3314:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBG_871X_SEL_NL’
   DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "byte5:%s%s\n"
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic'
Makefile:1696: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I can use the wifi dongle with the current kernel driver (rtl8xxxu), but with some issues like Low signal power, the dongle led don't work and sometimes i have to unplug and plug the dongle again to connect. Since the vendor website provides an updated version, i want to give it a try.

Edit:
Here is what lsusb returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 090c:6300 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:0107  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0000:0538  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2a7a:0c18  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

modinfo rtl8xxxu | grep 0107:

```
alias:          usb:v2357p0107d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
```

Edit: [Here's the link of the driver in TP-Link website.](https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201805/20180514/TP-Link_Driver_Linux_series8_beta.zip) and the [support page.](https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN821N.html#Driver)

Comment: `"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"` figure out what this means.
`"please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"` consider this.
`/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/adriano/Downloads/TL-WN821N_V6_Linux/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:267:8: error: ‘_timer {aka struct timer_list}’ has no member named ‘data’` there's a disagreement between your system and theirs about what a `struct timer_list` looks like. The other errors imply the same type of mismatch. Check REQUIREMENTS in `README.*`

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `lsusb`

Comment: @waltinator, intalled libelf-dev and tryied to compile againit failed. There's no Readme in the package. I've doenloaded from TP-Link website (https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN821N.html#Driver). There's a pdf with intructions how to build the driver. Still i couldn't compile it.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `modinfo rtl8xxxu | grep 0107`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, still no luck with TP-Link driver. Guess i'll stay with the kernel
default driver. Hope someday this dongle works correctly...
Thanks you for help me.